AWS Amplify acts as localhost:3000 in origin after my NextJS 14 app has been deployed for production and checks for CORS whitelist in the middleware
After deploying my NextJS (14.2.20) app to AWS Amplify with GitHub, the origin on the server side is supposed to be the domain of the said app so that I can check for CORS.
For example: https://main.xxxxxx.amplifyapp.com
But instead the origin is: https://localhost:3000
Note that this problem never occurs when I deploy it to Vercel and also locally works too even though my local origin has a different port (http://localhost:88888). So I'm guessing something is wrong with the AWS configurations or the lack thereof.
Here is how I check for CORS whitelist inside my middleware.ts:
export const middleware = async (req: NextRequest) => {
const origin = req.nextUrl.origin;

if (!publicEnv.CORS_WHITELIST?.includes(origin)) {
 return NextResponse.json({ error: `Access denied. Environment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}. Your Origin: ${origin} | Whitelist: ${publicEnv.CORS_WHITELIST}` }, { status: 405 })
}
...

Here is the result from the deployment:
{"error":"Access denied. Environment: production. Your Origin: https://localhost:3000 | Whitelist: https://main.xxxxxx.amplifyapp.com"}
Here is more info if needed.
Inside the amplify.yml file:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - .npm/**/*
      - node_modules/**/*

Also regardless if the customHttp.yml file is empty OR has this content it still doesn't work, I've tested both scenarios:
customHeaders:
  - pattern: "**/*"
    headers:
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        value: https://main.xxxxxx.amplifyapp.com
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        value: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
      - key: Access-Control-Allow-Methods
        value: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS

For the scripts inside the package.json file, I've tried these two scenarios as well.
First Scenario:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 88888",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 88888",
    "lint": "next lint"
}

Second Scenario:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 88888",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
}

As you can see from the result that it's marked as production and still uses localhost as origin.

Instead of:
export const middleware = async (req: NextRequest) => {
const origin = req.nextUrl.origin;

if (!publicEnv.CORS_WHITELIST?.includes(origin)) {
 return NextResponse.json({ error: `Access denied. Environment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}. Your Origin: ${origin} | Whitelist: ${publicEnv.CORS_WHITELIST}` }, { status: 405 })
}
...

I've done:
export const middleware = async (req: NextRequest) => {
const host = req.headers.get("host");
    const protocol = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https" : "http";
    const origin = `${protocol}://${host}`;

    if (!origin || !publicEnv.CORS_WHITELIST?.includes(origin)) {
        return NextResponse.json({ error: `Access denied. Environment: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}. Your Origin: ${origin} | Whitelist: ${publicEnv.CORS_WHITELIST}` }, { status: 405 })
    }
...


Please do not roll back useful edits by the community
